# Compound Queries (Specifically .or()) on iOS using the Parse API for Unity

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

So I have a script in Unity that uses the .Or() method of ParseQueries to get some rows from our Parse database. Specifically to retrieve rows that represent matches with the corresponding usernames for both players.

The code in question looks like this.

```
    var query1 = ParseObject.GetQuery("Game").WhereEqualTo("hostUsername", (string)ParseUser.CurrentUser["username"]).WhereEqualTo("p2username", parseUsername);
    var query2 = ParseObject.GetQuery("Game").WhereEqualTo("hostUsername", parseUsername).WhereEqualTo("p2username", (string)ParseUser.CurrentUser["username"]);

    //Runs both query 1 and query 2, and counts the combined results.
    query1.Or(query2).CountAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
    {

        int count = t.Result;

        if (count != 0) 
        {
            query1.Or(query2).FirstAsync().ContinueWith(y =>
            {
             //Do stuff with the first result
            });
        }
    });
```

This works just fine on Android devices, no problem there. However, when we build our game for iOS devices, or at least iPhones, we get the following error message:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.<CreateConcatIterator>c__Iterator1<Parse.ParseQuery<Parse.ParseObject>>     doesn't implement interface System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Parse.ParseQuery<T>>
* Assertion: should not be reached at mini-trampolines.c:183
```

I did some googling and it seems like this might be a bug in either the Facebook SDK or Parse's API? There were a handful of threads about it on the old Parse forums, but no solution that I could see.

Someone made this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/750897958275392/ post on the developers page for Facebook and in July one of the devs there said that they are still working on it.

My question is simply, has anyone encountered the issue and discovered a solution and/or a workaround? Pending a response from Facebook, I'm guessing I need to take another approach to this, but I'm lost as to what that might be.

Greatly appreciate any responses and help anyone can give.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? I'm running into the same issue and can't find any way to make it work... Thanks!

Comment: Ive run into this issue before in a separate situation. For those that don`t know, a trampoline is a how generics are implemented in iOS. This specific error is deep down in the mono code. Not fun.

Comment: I ended up just doing 2 separate queries instead of the .or() as I couldn't find a solution otherwise. Sorry I couldn't be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the Unity SDK for parse, subscribe to this bug for updates: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/750897958275392/